# How do i change state of a reducer which contains a firestore async function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

i am configuring this reducer so that after creating a document on firestore, it would return the payload as the reducer state. i tried using redux thunk but i dont think im using it well because this code would remove the reducer from redux devtool extension.

```
  switch (action.type) {

    case "create-chatroom":
      const room = action.payload.roomName;
      return (dispatch) => {
        const user = Auth.currentUser;
        Db.collection("chatrooms")
          .doc(action.payload.roomName)
          .set({
            authUsers: [user.uid],
            messages: {
              data: {
                sender: "notification",
                text: `${action.payload.roomName} has been created`,
                timestamp: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              },
            },
            public: action.payload.public,
          })
          .then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: "set-current-room", payload: room });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: "set-room", payload: state });
          });
      };

case "set-current-room":
      return action.payload;
```

Comment: removing the whole reducer? sounds like you might be overwriting all the initial state somewhere. have you hooked up thunk to be used in middleware?

Comment: If the code you are showing is reducer code and not an action creator then you are definitely using [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) wrong